# Accessing two radio buttons at once Java

Tags: java, sql

I have Java Application created and I can't figure out why i can't access two radio buttons at once. My code is

```
if(rb2005.isSelected()&&rbQ3.isSelected()){   
            try{
            String query = "select PP.BusinessEntityID,PP.FirstName,PP.LastName,SO.PurchaseOrderNumber, SO.OrderDate, '$' + cast(SO.SubTotal as varchar(10)) AmountSold from Person.Person PP inner join Sales.SalesOrderHeader SO on SO.SalesPersonID = PP.BusinessEntityID where SO.OrderDate between '07/01/2005' and '09/30/2005' order by SO.OrderDate asc";        
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            //pstmt.setString(1, search);
            set = pstmt.executeQuery();

            rbQ1.setEnabled(false);
            rbQ2.setEnabled(false);

            picLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/2005Quarter3.jpeg")));
            while(set.next()){
            String fname = set.getString("FirstName");
            String lname = set.getString("LastName");
            String pNum = set.getString("PurchaseOrderNumber");
            String amountSold = set.getString("AmountSold");

            textArea.append(fname+" "+lname+"   "+pNum+" "+amountSold+"\n");
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have the buttons displaying an image to a label with works if one radio button is selected. But returns a JOptionPane.showMessage(null,e.getMessage) as null. Please help.

Comment: Well...the conventional behavior of radio buttons is to only allow one selection out of n choices. Perhaps you want checkbox instead

Answer (score 1):

[Radio buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) are groups of buttons in which, by convention, only one button at a time can be selected, therefore you can not make the verification `if(rb2005.isSelected()&&rbQ3.isSelected())`.

What you want to use are **Checkboxes** -- an item that can be selected or deselected, and which displays its state to the user. By convention, any number of checkboxes in a group can be selected.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) you can learn how to use checkboxes.

Comment: The point of the application is to search by year "rb2005" and by quarter "rbQ3". How can I have them both selected and display what i want without using if(rb2005.isSelected()&&rbQ3.isSelected())

Comment: Have you even read my answer? You can have them both selected using a Checkbox rather than a RadioButton.

Comment: I tried that and a NullPointerException error comes up